# How can I get the HTML code for the selected text and images in a UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview

I want to get the HTML code for the selected text (or text and images) in a UIWebView. 
Someone suggested to me the `selecteddomrange` function of the WebKit framework, but it works with Mac OS, and I need it in iOS.

Is there any way in iOS that I can get the HTML code for the selected text (or text and images) from a webview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIWebView`s

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

and get the `innerHTML` element property via a JS expression.

Have a look at the JS function `window.getSelection()`

I've not tested this but you most likely have to do it somehow via JS on iOS since the `UIWebView` API is much more limited than it's OSX counterpart.

Have a look at the [DOM Range Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html)

Comment: It's not woking for me . I also tried code using this link. If you have any idea,please let me know